# Efficient Firestore query on "dates"

Tags: performance, datetime, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a firestore db need to query on dates range.

My question : in terms of query efficiency, how should I store my dates?

- as numbers?
- as firestore Timestamp?
- (my guess is that string format is bad !)

- Knowing that my queries will only be on day (not hours or seconds), is it more efficient to query on a field that has just day-precision, or can I keep better precision?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For performance, it doesn't really matter how you store the date.  The index created for the date field will be able to find the range of documents equally well for each one.  The performance of Firestore queries is based on the number of documents matched by the query, not the type of data used.

Comment: "For performance, it doesn't really matter how you store the date." It really does. Suppose you store the date as `MM/dd/yyyy` or even `dd/MM/yyyy` format - how would you propose querying that via a date range? Sure, deciding between a number (derived in a sensible way), Timestamp, or a *sensible* string format (yyyy-MM-dd) may not make much difference, but you do need to choose a sensible format in order to make the query feasible.

Comment: @JonSkeet That doesn't really sound like a performance issue - it sounds like a capability problem.  If the date isn't formatted in a way that's helpful for the query, then all bets are off.  But Firestore is going to handle the query with the same performance as it would any other query that would return X documents.